# How to insert image into collapsed row using xlsxwritter python?

Tags: python, excel, odoo, xlsxwriter

How to insert image into collapsed row using xlsxwritter python ?
xlsxwriter == 1.1.2
python 3.7
[Current logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsQMn.png)
There are 3 levels of grouping, How can I insert an image in the second column for the 3rd level of grouping.

```py
                sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
                sheet.outline_settings(symbols_below=False)

                sheet.set_column(0, 1, 18)
                sheet.set_column(2, 2, 36)
                sheet.set_column(3, 7, 18)
                sheet.set_row(0, 70)

                sheet.write(0, 0, _("Header"), table_header_format)
                sheet.write(0, 1, _("Header 1"), table_header_format)
                sheet.write(0, 2, _("Header 2"), table_header_format)

                row = 1
                for categ_id, values in categ_id_values.items():
                    sheet.set_row(row, None, None, {"level": 1, "hidden": False})
                    sheet.merge_range(row, 0, row, col, categ_id.name, table_group_format_align_left)
                    row += 1
                    description = values["description"]
                    description_size = len(description.split("\n")) * 15
                    sheet.set_row(row, description_size, None, {"level": 2, "hidden": True})
                    sheet.merge_range(row, 0, row, col, description, table_format_align_left_bold)
                    row += 1
                    sheet.set_row(row, None, None, {"level": 2, "hidden": True})
                    sheet.merge_range(row, 0, row, col, "", table_format_align_left_bold)
                    row += 1
                    for product_template_data in values["product_templates"]:
                        product_template_id = product_template_data.get("product_template_id")
                        product_template_specification, row_size = self.get_product_template_specification(product_template_data["attributes"], product_template_id)
                        sheet.set_row(row, row_size, None, {"level": 2, "hidden": True, "collapsed": True})
                        sheet.write(row, 0, product_template_id.display_name, table_format_template_align_left)
                        sheet.write(row, 1, "", table_format_align_left)
                        sheet.write(row, 2, product_template_specification, table_format_align_left)
                        col = 3
                        for pricelist_id in pricelist_ids:
                            sheet.write(row, col, "", table_pricelist_format)
                            col += 1
                        row += 1
                        for index, product_variant_id in enumerate(product_template_data["product_variant_ids"]):
                            index += 1
                            image_size = 13 * index
                            sheet.set_row(row, None, None, {"level": 3, "hidden": True, "collapsed": True})
                            sheet.write(row, 0, product_variant_id.name, table_format_model_bold_align_left)
                            sheet.write(row, 1, "", table_format_align_left)

                            specifications, row_size = self.get_product_product_specification(
                                product_template_data["attributes"],
                                product_variant_id)
                            sheet.set_row(row, row_size, None, {"level": 3, "hidden": True, "collapsed": True})
                            sheet.write(row, 2, specifications, table_format_align_left)
                            col = 2
                            for pricelist_id in pricelist_ids:
                                col += 1
                                pricelist_line_id = product_variant_id.product_template_pricelist_line_ids.filtered(lambda line_id: line_id.pricelist_id == pricelist_id)
                                sheet.write(row, col, pricelist_line_id.price if pricelist_line_id else 0, table_pricelist_format)
                            row += 1
```

At the moment it is inserted like this:
[At the moment it is inserted like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otLUU.png)

Is it possible to implement grouping with a picture in xlsxwritter?

Code for inserting pictures:

```
                            image = self.download_image()
                            if image:
                                sheet.set_row(row, None, None, {"level": 3, "hidden": True, "collapsed": True})
                                file_name = "Test.jpeg"
                                sheet.insert_image(0 + image_size, 1, file_name, {
                                    "image_data": image,
                                    "x_scale": 0.13,
                                    "y_scale": 0.22,
                                    "object_position": 1,
                                })
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does `"object_position": 4` help for your use case. See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_object_positioning.html

Comment: @jmcnamara Helped updating the version of the library, xlsxwriter == 1.1.2 did not contain an object_position attribute, but had only positioning, which worked differently.